# Search on Redux toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to search for a customer with either first_name or last_name argument and display it on my table but it doesn't work. I tried deconstructing first_name and last_name still no luck. If I console log term I can see the what is typed What am I doing wrong please?

customerSlice.js

```js
const initialState = {
  customer: [],
  customers: [],
  isLoading: true,
  isError: false,
  isSuccess: false,
  message: "",
};

// Search customer
export const searchCustomer = createAsyncThunk(
  "customer/searchCustomer",
  async({
    first_name,
    last_name
  }, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const token = thunkAPI.getState().auth.user.token;
      return await customerService.searchCustomer(first_name, last_name, token);
    } catch (error) {
      const message =
        (error.response &&
          error.response.data &&
          error.response.data.message) ||
        error.message ||
        error.toString();
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message);
    }
  }
);

extraReducers: (builder) => {
  .addCase(searchCustomer.pending, (state) => {
      state.isLoading = true;
      state.isError = false;
    })
    .addCase(searchCustomer.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.isLoading = false;
      state.isError = false;
      state.customer = action.payload.payload;
    })
    .addCase(searchCustomer.rejected, (state, action) => {
      state.isLoading = false;
      state.isError = true;
      state.message = action.error.message;
    })
},
```

customerService.js

```js
const searchCustomer = async(first_name, last_name, token) => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
  };

  const response = await axios.get(
    `http://localhost:8000/api/v1/customer/search?q=${first_name, last_name}`,
    config
  );

  return response.data;
};
```

```js
const Search = () => {

  const [term, setTerm] = useState('')

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    dispatch(searchCustomer(term));
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <Input
        value={term}
        onChange={(e) => setTerm(e.target.value)}
        fontSize="xs"
        py="11px"
        color={mainText}
        placeholder="Search customers by any fields on this table"
        borderRadius="inherit"
      />
    </InputGroup>
    </form>
  );
};

export default Search;
```